# NSCache get object from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscache

I am new to NSCache, I want to cache the response data and use it. So my `[cache setobject]` is in class A and I need to get it from class B using `[cache objectForKey]`. But it is always `NULL`.It works in same class as below..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ios.eezytutorials.com/sample-files/sample-dictionary-plist.plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSCache *cache = [[NSCache alloc]init];
[cache setObject:dict forKey:url];
NSLog(@"%@",[cache objectForKey:url]);
```

How to get that from different class?

Answer (score 1):

NSCache is not a singleton or shared instance. If you want to use the contents of a specific instance, you could place your NSCache instance on AppDelegate or create your own singleton class to manage it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried , extended NSCache.. created singleton but still getting NULL..                                                                                               MyDataCache* _cache = [MyDataCache sharedQDataCache];
        
        
        //MyRequestDataModel* prevCachedData = [_cache objectForKey:[self.url absoluteString]];
        
        NSLog(@"%@",[_cache objectForKey:[self.url absoluteString]]);

Comment: Could you update your question with this singleton implementation? Maybe I can help you with this.